# CUDA Toolkit Installation Fails "Could not create folder" "Access is denied"

Tags: cuda

This is a self-answered post documenting a problem I encountered:

When I run cuda_11.5.0_496.13_win10.exe as administrator on windows 10 and CUDA Setup extracts the installer to my computer, it leaves me the error:

CUDA Setup Package: error
Could not create folder “C:\Users[myName]\AppData\Local\Temp\CUDA\CUDADevelopment”. Access is denied.

I’ve tried various versions from CUDA 9.0-11.5 and they all fail; as does extracting to a different folder. I have drivers installed and they work properly (I’ve checked them through OpenGL, and CUDA-based python libraries with their own CUDA installations use GPU successfully).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. rename the .exe file to a .7z file (e.g. cuda_11.5.0_496.13_win10.exe → cuda_11.5.0_496.13_win10.7z). I used the linux mv command.
2. Unzip the file with 7zip or winzip into any temporary folder.
3. run setup.exe (I ran as admin)